# Golang Couchbase integration throwing errors on setting/getting

Tags: go, couchbase, go-couchbase

Implementing https://github.com/couchbase/go-couchbase

However - no matter what I do - with various types of connections - I get errors when setting/getting keys.

```
vbmap smaller than vbucket list: 18119 vs. []
```

Code Example below (have tried many variations)

```
b, err := couchbase.GetBucket("http://somebucket:somepassword@myserver:8091/",
       "default", "somebucket")
mf(err,"con")

err = b.Set("somekey", 0, map[string]interface{}{"x": 1})
  mf(err, "set")
```

Comment: I did: vbmap smaller than vbucket list: 18119 vs. []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to connect to a memcached bucket. go-couchbase doesn't support buckets of type memcached.

Comment: Yes I was trying to connect to a memcached bucket. That's unfortunate it's not supported - Thanks for the answer

Comment: You could try with using the stubs in couchbase/gomemcached and see if that might work for you. Set the vbucket number to 0 in all your API calls.